# Variables declared outside function

Tags: python

I was just trying to see how variable scopes work and ran into the following situation (all ran from the terminal):

```
x = 1
def inc():
    x += 5

inc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in inc
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I was thinking maybe I don't have access to x in my method, so I tried:

```
def inc():
    print(x)

1
```

So this works. Now I know I could just do:

```
 def inc():
     global x
     x += 1
```

And this would work, but my question is why does the first example fail? I mean I would expect since `print(x)` worked that `x` is visible inside the function so why would the `x += 5` fail?

Comment: Less then 24 hours ago someone asked a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8934772/1132524), maybe you want to take a look.

Comment: Everybody is complicating matter more than necessary, while missing the most important *feature* of using `global`. Namely that you can define a variable `x` **after** the function definition, and then still use/access it inside that function with `global x`.

Comment: In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be local unless explicitly declared as global. For further details refer to this link: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score 67):

Unlike languages that employ 'true' lexical scoping, Python opts to have specific 'namespaces' for variables, whether it be `global`, `nonlocal`, or local. It could be argued that making developers consciously code with such namespaces in mind is more explicit, thus more understandable. I would argue that such complexities make the language more unwieldy, but I guess it's all down to personal preference.

Here are some examples regarding `global`:-

```
>>> global_var = 5
>>> def fn():
...     print(global_var)
... 
>>> fn()
5
>>> def fn_2():
...     global_var += 2
...     print(global_var)
... 
>>> fn_2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fn_2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'global_var' referenced before assignment
>>> def fn_3():
...     global global_var
...     global_var += 2
...     print(global_var)
... 
>>> fn_3()
7
```

The same patterns can be applied to `nonlocal` variables too, but this keyword is only available to the latter Python versions.

In case you're wondering, `nonlocal` is used where a variable isn't global, but isn't within the function definition it's being used. For example, a `def` within a `def`, which is a common occurrence partially due to a lack of multi-statement lambdas. There's a hack to bypass the lack of this feature in the earlier Pythons though, I vaguely remember it involving the use of a single-element list...

Note that writing to variables is where these keywords are needed. Just reading from them isn't ambiguous, thus not needed. Unless you have inner `def`s using the same variable names as the outer ones, which just should just be avoided to be honest.

Comment: In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be local unless explicitly declared as global. For further information refer to this link: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score 41):

When Python parses a function, it notes when a variable **assignment** is made. When there is an assignment, it assumes by default that that variable is a local variable. To declare that the assignment refers to a global variable, you must use the `global` declaration.

When you **access** a variable in a function, its value is looked up using the [LEGB scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

---

So, the first example

```
x = 1
def inc():
    x += 5
inc()
```

produces an `UnboundLocalError` because Python determined `x` inside `inc` to be a local variable,

while accessing `x` works in your second example

```
def inc():
    print x
```

because here, in accordance with the LEGB rule, Python looks for `x` in the local scope, does not find it, then looks for it in the extended scope, still does not find it, and finally looks for it in the global scope successfully.

Comment: In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be local unless explicitly declared as global. For further information refer to this link: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score 10):

The local names for a function are decided when the function is *defined*:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def inc():
...     x += 5
...     
>>> inc.__code__.co_varnames
('x',)
```

In this case, `x` exists in the local namespace.  Execution of `x += 5` requires a pre-existing value for `x` (for integers, it's like `x = x + 5`), and this fails at function call time because the local name is unbound - which is precisely why the exception `UnboundLocalError` is named as such.

Compare the other version, where `x` is not a local variable, so it can be resolved at the global scope instead:

```
>>> def incg():
...    print(x)
...    
>>> incg.__code__.co_varnames
()
```

Similar question in faq:  http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value