# read multiple data from csv

Tags: html, python-3.x, csv, flask

I have a csv file and I need to read it as list and add every item to input form, but when I use specific `option value` I can add them by pressing comma, but when I read them from .csv file this method does not work. What can be the problem?

```
with open('templates/Testing.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        myvalues = next(reader)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def page_show():
    return render_template('includes/default.html', myvalues=myvalues)
```

from .csv method(it does not work by pressing comma)

```
<form action="/action" method="POST">
  <input list="myvalues" multiple>
  <datalist id="myvalues">
    {% for val in myvalues %}
        <option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

adding specific value method(it works by pressing comma)

```
<form action="/action" method="POST">
  <input list="myvalues" multiple>
  <datalist id="myvalues">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">one</option>
        <option value="three">one</option>
        <option value="four">one</option>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean "by pressing comma"? Pressing where? Also, how is your question related to Python?

Comment: @DYZ pressing in my input. It based on flask, python

Comment: Please tag it as flask.

Comment: @DYZ done. Please check it again.

Comment: You need to edit the question with the python code related to the problem.

Comment: @v25 please check it again

Comment: Can you confirm that `{% for val in myvalues %}` is working by printing the value of `val` for example?

Comment: @Chiel, No. I have checked it and do not see values in cmd. Could you please help with the issue, if it is needed I can send all code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can solve at least a part of your problem.

<del>First of all, the `next()` function only returns the next item of the list (csv data). Whereas I reckon you should have used the `list()` function.
This function creates a list where you can loop through in `default.html`.</del>

To solve the problem of the variables not being accessible in `default.html`, it probably gives you the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myvalues' referenced before assignment`. Which means that you are trying to asign `myvalues` to `myvalues` but python doesn't know where to look for that variable. See more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943933/variables-declared-outside-function).

So how would you solve this? Just rename the `myvalues` to something like `myData`. See the full code below:

#### main.py

```py
myvalues = []
with open('templates/Testing.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        myvalues = next(reader)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def page_show():
    return render_template('includes/default.html', myData=myvalues)
```

#### default.html:

```py
<form action="/action" method="POST">
  <input list="myvalues" multiple>
  <datalist id="myvalues">
    {% for val in myData %}
        <option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Btw, that

> I can add them by pressing comma, but when I read them from .csv file this method does not work

I have no idea what you mean, pleas elaborate.

Hope this helps! If not, please comment

Comment: thanks for replying, but in your sample I can see all rows in input from csv. I need to use only first row of my .csv file. All values in the first row.

Comment: when I say add them by pressing comma I mean I need to select first value from dropdown, and add other values, by pressing comma or automatically, I mean make a loop for dropdown to select values again and again. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist). Please assist, I asked such question many times, no one could help.

Comment: Hi, Ill change the answer according to the first comment. However for the second comment you should take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404139/8902440) seems the most simple. Hope this helps