# Global and local variables in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, global-variables

I am learning Python. A book on Python 3 says the following code should work fine:

```
def funky():
    print(myvar)
    myvar = 20
    print(myvar)

myvar = 10
funky()
```

But when I run it in Python 3.3, I got the

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myvar' referenced before assignment
```

error. My understanding is that the first `print(myvar)` in `funky` should be 10 since it's a global variable. The second `print(myvar)` should be 20 since a local `myvar` is defined to be 20. What is going on here? Please help clarify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [local var referenced before assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934772/local-var-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: While the duplicate answers your question, the simplest answer is that you can add `global myvar` at the start of the function if you want to treat it as a global variable. If you ever assign to `myvar` in the function (as you do in the line `myvar = 20`), Python assumes it is a local variable and thinks you are referring to it before it is defined.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Is this `global` new in Python 3.3 since that book didn't mention it?

Comment: No, `global` has been around for a while. Are you sure that the book wasn't giving this as an example of code that *didn't* work?

Comment: @DavidRobinson No. The book is at [here](http://inventwithpython.com/IYOCGwP_book1.pdf). The bottom of page 66.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `global` in your function before assigning a value.

```
def funky():
    global myvar
    print(myvar)
    myvar = 20
    print(myvar)

myvar = 10
funky()
```

Note that you can print the value without calling global because you can access global variables without using `global`, but attempting to assign a value will require it.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/executionmodel.html):

> Each occurrence of a name in the program text refers to the binding of
>   that name established in the innermost function block containing the
>   use.

It means that unless you declare it `global` or `nonlocal` (nested functions) then `myvar` is a local variable or a free variable (if `myvar` is not defined in the function).

The book is incorrect. Within the same block the name represents the same variable (local variable `myvar` in your example, you can't use it until you define it even if there is a global variable with the same name). Also you *can* change values outside a function i.e., [the text at the end of page 65 is also incorrect](http://inventwithpython.com/IYOCGwP_book1.pdf). The following works:

```
def funky(): # local
    myvar = 20 
    print(myvar) # -> 20
myvar = 10 # global and/or local (outside funky())
funky()
print(myvar) # -> 10 (note: the same)
```

```
def funky(): # global
    global myvar
    print(myvar) # -> 10
    myvar = 20
myvar = 10
funky() 
print(myvar) # -> 20 (note: changed)
```

```
def funky(): # free (global if funky is not nested inside an outer function)
    print(myvar) # -> 10
myvar = 10
funky()
```

```
def outer():
    def funky():  # nonlocal
        nonlocal myvar
        print(myvar) # -> 5
        myvar = 20
    myvar = 5 # local
    funky()
    print(myvar) # -> 20 (note: changed)
outer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python "assumes" that we want a local variable due to the assignment to myvar inside of funky(), so the first print statement throws ## UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myvar' referenced before assignment ## error message. Any variable which is changed or created inside of a function is local, if it hasn't been declared as a global variable. To tell Python, that we want to use the global variable, we have to use the keyword "global", as can be seen in the following example:

```
def f():
  global s
  print s
  s = "That's clear."
  print s 


s = "Python is great!" 
f()
print s
```