# When is symbol table created in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, symbol-table

```
def square():
    print(a)
    a = 10
    b = a*a
    return b

a = 2

print(square())
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

```
def square():
    print(a)
    #a = 10
    b = a*a
    return b

a = 2

print(square())
```

I just want to make sure why the second scenario is right while the first is wrong.

> The execution of a function introduces a new symbol table used for the
>   local variables of the function. More precisely, all variable
>   assignments in a function store the value in the local symbol table;
>   whereas variable references first look in the local symbol table, then
>   in the local symbol tables of enclosing functions, then in the global
>   symbol table, and finally in the table of built-in names.

While interpreter is going through the definition of the function it creates a symbol table. It first thinks 'a' as global(due to print(a)) and later creates 'a' in local symbol table(Due to assignment).

So while actually executing the function, 'a' is a local which has no binding. Hence the error.

Is my reasoning right about symbol tables??

**Update**: Adding global after assignment:

```
def square():
    print(a)
    a = 10
    b = a*a
    global a
    return b

a = 2

print(square())

print(a)
```

Does `global a` statement remove name `'a'` from the local symbol table of `square` function?

Comment: Yep, that's my understanding as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global and local variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421733/global-and-local-variables-in-python)

Comment: Yeah the question might be a duplicate. But I wanted the discussion to be in terms of symbol tables

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope issue. Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/293097/1741450

> Variables in scopes other than the local function's variables can be accessed, but can't be rebound to new parameters without further syntax. Instead, assignment will create a new local variable instead of affecting the variable in the parent scope.

The first example is wrong since a cannot be modified.