# Another capitalise every odd char of the string solution

Tags: python, string

I just started studying Python and created some kind of task for myself that I'm struggling to solve...

So, I'm on chapter on working with strings (accessing strings by index, changing etc).

My task is - capitalize every odd char of the string. I saw the solution here: [Capitalise every other letter in a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865563/capitalise-every-other-letter-in-a-string-in-python)

but I don't like it... wanted to solve this by slices. So what I produced is followig code:

```
T = 'somesampletexthere'  
R=""

for i in range(0, len(T[1::2])):
        R+=T[::2][i].upper()+T[1::2][i].lower()

print R
```

This code works great when there are even number of chars, for example with TESTTEXT but when the number is odd like here in EXAMPLE it will skipp last char (in this case E)

This is because the range is till `len(T[1::2]))` (length of even characters) but if I'll try the length of odd characters `len(T[::2]))` I'll get error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

logically because number of odd chars will always be bigger on 1 (in case of text with odd number of characters).

So, my question is - how can I supress the error? So Python just return null or something in case the index is out of range of the given string?

Or any other solutions of the task using slices?

Comment: If you're just starting Python you should _seriously_ consider learning Python 3. Python 2 will no longer be supported after 2020.

Comment: @PM 2Ring just wanted to start with 2 in order to understnad more python 3 learning books :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are right to prefer a slicing solution over those in the linked question. (OTOH, that's a slightly different question because it skips spaces). However, your current code is rather inefficient because it recreates the `T[::2]` and `T[1::2]` slices on every iteration of the `for` loop. Also, calling `.upper` or `.lower` on single characters is less efficient than calling it on larger strings.

Here's an efficient way to do this using slicing.

```
T = 'somesampletexthere'
R = [''] * len(T)
R[::2], R[1::2] = T[::2].upper(), T[1::2].lower()
R = ''.join(R)
print(R)
```

**output**

```
SoMeSaMpLeTeXtHeRe
```

It may help you understand what's going on if we split up those assignments to `R`.

```
T = 'somesampletexthere'
R = [''] * len(T)
R[::2] = T[::2].upper()
print(R)
R[1::2] = T[1::2].lower()
print(R)
R = ''.join(R)
print(R)
```

**output**

```
['S', '', 'M', '', 'S', '', 'M', '', 'L', '', 'T', '', 'X', '', 'H', '', 'R', '']
['S', 'o', 'M', 'e', 'S', 'a', 'M', 'p', 'L', 'e', 'T', 'e', 'X', 't', 'H', 'e', 'R', 'e']
SoMeSaMpLeTeXtHeRe
```

We can do those slice assignments in either order:

```
T = 'somesampletexthere'
R = [''] * len(T)
R[1::2] = T[1::2].lower()
print(R)
R[::2] = T[::2].upper()
print(R)
R = ''.join(R)
print(R)
```

**output**

```
['', 'o', '', 'e', '', 'a', '', 'p', '', 'e', '', 'e', '', 't', '', 'e', '', 'e']
['S', 'o', 'M', 'e', 'S', 'a', 'M', 'p', 'L', 'e', 'T', 'e', 'X', 't', 'H', 'e', 'R', 'e']
SoMeSaMpLeTeXtHeRe
```

---

Just for fun, here's an alternative strategy that zips the upper & lower case strings together. We use `izip_longest` (or `zip_longest` in Python 3) so we can handle strings that have an odd length.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

T = 'somesampletexthere'
R = ''.join([c for t in izip_longest(T[::2].upper(), T[1::2].lower(), fillvalue='') for c in t])
print(R)
```

Although this version does it in one line I prefer my first version: I find it more readable, and it's probably a little faster.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Thats exactly what I wanted and the direction in which I was trying to investigate.

Comment: One question, here, I just can't understand the magic... so T[::2].upper() and T[1::2].lower() are strings and R at the moment of running 'join' is a list of strings in correct order... how this is happening? :)

Comment: @Akhiles: Magic! :) When you do a slice assignment to a list from a string Python unpacks the string into the list elements. It's similar to what happens if you do `a,b,c = 'abc'` - the string gets unpacked into the `(a,b,c)` tuple.

Comment: I mean I got the moment of assigment string to list (it's like adding char to float - you will get float, as I understood). So R[::2], R[1::2] are lists of characters already, I didn't get the trick why join() joined them in correct order... I guess I'll go and read about this function :) anyway thanks a lt! You rock!

Comment: @Akhiles Python is strongly typed, it won't let you add a char to a float. The chars are in the correct order because of the way we do the slice assignment: the transformed even chars get assigned to `R[::2]` and the transformed odd chars get assigned to`R[1::2]`, `.join` doesn't affect the order in any way, it just builds a string from the strings in the list you pass it.

Comment: sorry, I ment integer to float :)

Comment: sorry maybe to be dumb :( but I'm trying to get everything... so after assigment I print results of two R lists
print R[::2], R[1::2] and get: ['S', 'M', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'T', 'X', 'H', 'R', 'G'] ['o', 'e', 'a', 'p', 'e', 'e', 't', 'e', 'e'] so in my understnading join should join them to string "SMSMLTXHRGoeapeetee" but why it works as we want... don't get... UPD, I get it... i get it! sorry , I get it when I just printed R :) without slices

Comment: @Akhiles: I've added a little more explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and test for odd and even indices using a ternary operator. Then use `join` to *join* the string:

```
>>> T = 'somesampletexthere'
>>> ''.join(x.upper() if i%2 else x.lower() for i, x in enumerate(T))
'sOmEsAmPlEtExThErE'
```

You could handle whitespaces by using an external counter object provided by [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count()
>>> T = 'some sample text here'
>>> ''.join(x if x.isspace() else (x.upper() if next(c)%2 else x.lower()) for x in T)
'sOmE sAmPlE tExT hErE'
```

Comment: What if the string has spaces in it?

Comment: @Andy The spaces are left as is. `upper` or `lower` will not modify them.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the link he provided showed that he wanted to capitalize every other letter in the string. So you have to ignore the spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Its not the direction in which I was investigated, but it looks much better than in solution provided in separate thread, thanks a lot!

Comment: `x.isspace()` is probably a little more efficient than `not x.strip()` because it only has to return the boolean rather than constructing the stripped string. And arguably a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not mutable, but lists are. So, we can [create a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787) of lowercase characters of the string (from `.lower()`), [use slice assignment](/questions/509211) to replace the appropriate ones with uppercase, and [join them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/) all back together:

```
lower_chars = list(T.lower())
lower_chars[::2] = T[::2].upper()
R = ''.join(lower_chars)
```