# How to uppercase specific letter

Tags: python, uppercase

I want to capitalise every 5th letter of name

Note: i only want to use .upper() method "not capitalize()"

I tried this but im getting IndexError: string index out of range

```
name = "Cristiano Ronaldo"

for t in range(0,len(name),5):
    name = str(name)[t].upper()
    print(name)
```

Comment: You are changing `name` to be a single letter... Don't you see that after the first `print`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalise every other letter in a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865563/capitalise-every-other-letter-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
"".join([char.upper() if index > 0 and (index - 1) % 5 == 0 else char for index, char in enumerate(name)])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first change the `str` to `list`:

```
l_name = list(name)

for i in range(0,len(l_name),5):
    l_name[i] = l_name[i].upper()

result = ''.join(l_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

name = "Cristiano Ronaldo"

```
print(''.join([ letter.upper() if (index+1) % 5 == 0 else letter for index,letter in enumerate(name)]))
```

`enumerate` method used to track the index of each letter in string while looping and for every multiple of 5 we are doing `letter.upper()` else `letter`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pythonic` way:

```
name = "cristiano Ronaldo"
print(''.join([l if i%5 else l.upper() for i, l in enumerate(name, 1)]))
```