# Ignore space in python

Tags: python, modulo

I need this code to ignore (not replace) spaces. Basically, it should capitalise every second letter of the alphabet only.

```py
def spaces(test_space):
    text = (str.lower, str.upper)
    return ''.join(text[i%2](x) for i, x in enumerate(test_space))

print(spaces('Ignore spaces and other characters'))
print(spaces('Ignore spaces and 3rd characters!'))
```

Output

```
iGnOrE SpAcEs aNd oThEr cHaRaCtErS

iGnOrE SpAcEs aNd 3Rd cHaRaCtErS
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and you can use the ASCII value to skip spaces

Comment: This is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865563/capitalise-every-other-letter-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: "capitalise every second letter of the alphabet only" how is `spaces` then `SpAcEs`, why is it not `sPaCeS` as `P` is the second letter?

Comment: @python_user I think he's showing what his program currently outputs. I agree it would be nice if he also showed his desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalise every other letter in a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865563/capitalise-every-other-letter-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework, so I'm only going to give suggestions and resources not complete code:

One way to do this would be to:

1. Replace every space with 2 of some character that can't appear in your text. for example use "$$". This can easily be done via python's `replace` function. We replace a space with 2 characters because each space is "throwing off" the index by one (mod 2), so by replacing each space by two characters corrects the problem (since 2 (mod 2) = 0).
2. Capitalize every other character using your current program
3. Replace each occurrence of '$$' with a space.
4. Put the spaces back using the indexes you saved

Output: `iGnOrE sPaCeS aNd 3rD cHaRaCtErS!`

Alternatively, you could iterate through the string (using a loop), keeping a position counter, but use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520932/python-remove-all-non-alphabet-chars-from-string) to ignore all non-Alphabet characters in the counter. You could also probably accomplish this succinctly via a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension), although it might be more confusing to read.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def spaces(test_space):
    return " ".join(
        [
            "".join(
                char.upper() if i % 2 == 1 else char.lower()
                for i, char in enumerate(word)
            )
            for word in test_space.split()
        ]
    )
```

outputs

```
iGnOrE sPaCeS aNd oThEr cHaRaCtErS
```

Comment: very nice use of a list comprehension, but isn't it supposed to ignore spaces? So the correct output should be: 
iGnOrE sPaCeS aNd OtHeR cHaRaCtErS

Comment: @EvanRosica now it works as you notes. A little bit messier though, since i had to join each word inside the comprehension into individual words as well as join the return value with spaces between them.

Comment: Since the comprehension becamse quite messy i formatted it with black and edited answer to let black decide about readability :P