# How can I avoid this "variable referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ran into the following problem. It's probably a simple solution, and has probably been asked here before, but I couldn't find it.

```
def a():
    liA = []
    def b():
        for i in liA:
            i += 1
        liB = generateList()
        for i in liB:
            i -= 1
        liA = liB

    def generateList():
        return [1,2,3,4]

    b()

a()
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'liA' referenced before assignment

Comment: Unless you're going to use the inner function as a closure the assignment `liA = liB` is next to useless.

Comment: *“but I couldn't find it”* – It didn’t occur to you to search for the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`liA` variable in `b()` function is never initialized.

So, you should edit the code in the followed way:

```
def a():
    liA = []
    def b(liA):
        for i in liA:
            i += 1
        liB = generateList()
        for i in liB:
            i -= 1
        liA = liB

    def generateList():
        return [1,2,3,4]

    b(liA)

a()
```

Hope I helped you!

Comment: Why should this variable be passed and shadowed as a parameter? There is clearly a `liA` variable that has been given a value.

Comment: Simply remove `liA = liB` there's no need to pass anything, `b` already knows what `liA` is but the assignment makes it a local variable. Secondly the assignment `liA = liB` is not going to affect the passed `liA` in any way.

Comment: becouse the liA variable with its given value is not visibile inside b() function.  Another solution may be to use a global variable, so decalre liA outside a() and define it global inside every function that use it.

Comment: @vathek ..but the outer `liA` variable *is* visible (take out the assignment of `liA = liB` and the original code will not throw an error); the issue comes when there is an *assignment* in scope. But *why*?

Comment: liA is a new local variable in b() and no the original one

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the **whole** stack trace you get a much better idea of how the error is happening.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jwp/Desktop/junk.py3", line 16, in <module>
    a()
  File "/Users/jwp/Desktop/junk.py3", line 14, in a
    b()
  File "/Users/jwp/Desktop/junk.py3", line 4, in b
    for i in liA:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'liA' referenced before assignment
```

So the error is being thrown when you call `b()` because you do not declare `liA` in the context of `b()` and then use it in the assignment `liA = liB`.

The most obvious answer would be to pass `liA` into `b()` as an argument. Like this:

```
def a():
    liA = []
    def b(inlist):
        liA = inlist
        for i in liA:
            i += 1
        liB = generateList()
        for i in liB:
            i -= 1
        liA = liB

    def generateList():
        return [1,2,3,4]

    b(liA)

a()
```

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Then [how does this work](https://repl.it/BE9O), where `var_in_a` is assigned in the parent (`a`) scope only? (Or maybe my question should be: 'how to rebind a variable in the containing scope'?)

Comment: @user2864740 Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8934902/216074). If you don’t assign to a variable within a scope, that variable isn’t locally declared, so the name lookup will check outer scopes for the name. That’s why you can read a variable from the outer scope just fine, but everything breaks when you start assigning to it. Then, it becomes a new variable.