# Why do immutable objects throw UnboundLocalError but mutable ones do not?

Tags: python, scope

When trying out code that assigns a GUID to class instances, I wrote something similar to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
x_id = 0 # immutable
x_id_list = [0] # mutable
def fx(x):
    global x_id # Disable to get "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x_id' referenced before assignment"
    if x is None:
        x_id += 2
        x_id_list[0] += 2
    else:
        x_id += 1
        x_id_list[0] += 1
        return (x_id - 1)
    return x_id

expected = [x for x in xrange(10)]
actual = [fx(x) for x in expected]
assert(expected == actual), "expected = {}, actual = {}".format(expected, actual)
print x_id_list
print x_id
```

Notice that only the immutable `x_id` throws the `UnboundLocalError` if its global scope is not defined, but the mutable `x_id_list` continues to work fine without its global scope needing to be defined.

Why is that?

Comment: I don't get an exception (and it shouldn't raise one either). Your program outputs `[10]` and `10` for me.

Comment: @Zizouz212 You need to comment out the `global x_id` line to get the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning to variable from parent function: "Local variable referenced before assignment"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934772/assigning-to-variable-from-parent-function-local-variable-referenced-before-as)

Comment: If you do `x_id_list += [2]`, you'll get an UnboundLocalError for that, too. It's not an issue of mutability.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that `x_id` is immutable (it isn't - [the integer value `0` is what's immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python)), but that you cannot assign to a variable defined outside a function without explicitly declaring your intent to do so via `global`. Mutating the list `x_id_list` refers to does not change the value of the `x_id_list` variable itself, and therefore is permitted.

If you tried to do `x_id_list += [1]` you'd run into the same error.  It is assigning to a *variable*, not mutating a *value*, that is the problem here.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring `global` for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if `global` was required for all global references, you’d be using `global` all the time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the `global` declaration for identifying side-effects.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8934902/113632) also goes into some more detail.

Comment: Good point about "Mutating the list x_id_list refers to does not change the value of the x_id_list". Some references would be good.

Answer (score -1):

That's because global scope variables are read-only in functions.

Since you're modifying the variable `x_id`, you need to reference it before using it, or Python will try to create a new variable that is local to the function.

Having used the `global` expression at the beginning of your function, you've told Python that you need to reference and modify that variable in your function. Since you are modifying the variable `x_id`, this happens. Since `x_id_list` is mutable, you are essentially not modifying it visibly (only internally, unlike `x_id`, where such a change is external), and therefore, you don't need the `global` keyword.

Comment: Do you maintain that x_id_list is not read-only but x_id is? Also references required.