# Why I can't get enclosing variable at the recursion function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

It's a function to count inversion in a list and return the count.

```
def count_inversion(sequence):
    count = 0

    def merge_count_inversion(L):
        if len(L) > 1:
            # split them.
            mid = len(L) // 2
            leftL = L[:mid]
            rightL = L[mid:]

            merge_count_inversion(leftL)
            merge_count_inversion(rightL)

            # merge them.
            i = j = k = 0
            while i < len(leftL) and j < len(rightL):
                if leftL[i] < rightL[j]:
                    L[k] = leftL[i]
                    i += 1
                else:# no equal situation.
                    L[k] = rightL[j]
                    j += 1
                    count+=j
                k += 1
            while i < len(leftL):#all right is inversion.
                count+=j
                L[k] = leftL[i]
                i += 1
                k += 1
            while j < len(rightL):
                L[k] = rightL[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1

    merge_count_inversion(list(sequence))

    return count
```

I use a enclosed count and I hope it can save the total number for all merge procession. However, it will be a local variable.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

I think I lose some concepts of recursion and the variable scope of python. Please tell me where I am wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `nonlocal` keyword.
add `nonlocal count` at the top of `merge_count_inversion`.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934772/assigning-to-variable-from-parent-function-local-variable-referenced-before-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that `count` isn't a local variable of `merge_count_inversion`, where you have used `count += j`. You should move `count = 0` in the function `merge_count_inversion`.

```
def count_inversion(sequence):

    def merge_count_inversion(L):
        count = 0
        if len(L) > 1:
            # split them.
            mid = len(L) // 2
            leftL = L[:mid]
            rightL = L[mid:]

            merge_count_inversion(leftL)
            merge_count_inversion(rightL)

            # merge them.
            i = j = k = 0
            while i < len(leftL) and j < len(rightL):
                if leftL[i] < rightL[j]:
                    L[k] = leftL[i]
                    i += 1
                else:# no equal situation.
                    L[k] = rightL[j]
                    j += 1
                    count+=j
                k += 1
            while i < len(leftL):#all right is inversion.
                count+=j
                L[k] = leftL[i]
                i += 1
                k += 1
            while j < len(rightL):
                L[k] = rightL[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1

    count = merge_count_inversion(list(sequence))

    return count
```

With **Python 3**

```
def count_inversion(sequence):
    count = 0    
    def merge_count_inversion(L):
        nonlocal count
        if len(L) > 1:
        ......

    merge_count_inversion(list(sequence))

    return count
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I just lose what I learned at the chapter about function in python...Variable can be found, but if we want to change the value, we must use global or nonlocal for situation.