# Why python is able to read `list` object from the outer scope but gives "referenced before assignment" error for the `int` object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am confused about these code:

```
def a():
    count1=[0]
    count2=0
    def b():
        count1[0]=count1[0]+1
        count2=count2+1
        print count1,count2
    b()
```

`count1` is announced as a list, it works well, while `count2` in `b()` will cause `referenced before assignment` error. Why?

Comment: There's no difference, but you're doing different things with them. Try `count1 = [count1[0] + 1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `count1` is the reference of the list and with `count1[0]` you try to access the 0th index of the `count1` list. Hence, when you do:

```
count1[0] = count1[0]+1
```

you are accessing the same `count1` object defined outside the `b()` function.

But that's not the case with `count2`. When you do:

```
 count2 = count2 + 1
```

You are trying to create a new `count2` object and in this case `b()` won't read the value of `count2` from the outer scope. In order to access the `count2` from the outer scope, you may use [**`nonlocal`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword (available since Python 3.x). Hence, your code should be as:

```
 # For Python 3.x

 def a():
    count2=0
    def b():
        nonlocal count2
        # ^ used here
        count2 = count2+1
    b()
```

But since you are using Python 2.x and `nonlocal` is not available in it, you may do a workaround via using `dict` to store `count2` variable as:

```
 # Workaround for Python 2.x

 def a():
    nonlocal_dict = {   # `dict` to store nonlocal variables
        'count2': 0
    } 
    def b():
        nonlocal_dict['count2'] = nonlocal_dict['count2']+1
        # ^ this `dict` will be available here
    b()
```

---

Please also take a look at:

- [Assigning to variable from parent function: “Local variable referenced before assignment”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934772/assigning-to-variable-from-parent-function-local-variable-referenced-before-as)
- [UnboundLocalError in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

First, you can access but not modify a variable which is beyond current scope. If you really want to do this, you have to use key word `nonlocal`.

Second, `count1` is actually a reference of an instance of list object, so if you don't change what it refer, it is not a modification direct to this variable.

Third, `count2` is a real value, and changing it's value means a modification direct to this variable.

You can test this by replace `count1[0]=count[0]+1` with `count1=list()`. It will cause exception too.

Comment: The variable is not `global` in this case.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq my bad, should be `nonlocal`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `b` assigns to `count2`, which implicitly creates `count2` as a local variable in `b`, which in turn makes all references to `count2` in `b` refer to this local variable. So at this line:

```
count2 = count2 + 1
#        ^^^^^^
```

You're trying to read from a variable that hasn't been initialized yet.

`count1` is different because `b` only reads from `count1`; it never assigns to it:

```
count1[0] = ...
```

This reads from `count1` to get the contained list, then modifies the first element.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use nonlocal keyword because in python variable follow LEGB rules means it is first look for local, enclosing, global , Built-in scope. Here you are accessing enclosing variable so you should use nonlocal in front of variable.

```
def a():
        count1=[0]
        count2=0
        def b():
            nonlocal count2
            count1[0]=count1[0]+1
            count2=count2+1
            print (count1,count2)
        b()

    a()
```